# Open two window together with a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I would like to begin by apologizing for my English.

I wish I could click on the button "Submit" form to open a new tab with the URL that sends the data to the form and also change the page to a thank you page. Except, well évidamment, current browsers block pages that open.

Here are two screen shoot contact form 7 to help :

HTML : http://prntscr.com/czhu6w
JS additionnals settings : http://prntscr.com/czhuo9

Thanks you ! <3

```js
on_sent_ok: "var civilite = encodeURI(jQuery('input[name="civilite"]').val());var nom = encodeURI(jQuery('input[name="nom"]').val());var prenom = encodeURI(jQuery('input[name="prenom"]');val());setTimeout("open('http://www.test.com/offre-decouverte?civilite='+civilite+'&nom='+nom+'&prenom='+prenom), 3000");location.replace('http://offre-decouverte.test.com/remerciements/');"
```

```html
<div class="floatL">

<p>Civilité *<br />
    [select* civilite include_blank "Mme." "M."]  </p>

<p>Nom *<br />
    [text* nom] </p>

<p>Prénom *<br />
    [text* prenom] </p>

<div class="clearFlorian">
<p><a href="http://offre-decouverte.test.com/remerciements/‎" target="_blank">[submit "VALIDER"]</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You provided too much code to debug (you could leave out most of the fields). Basically, you do `open` and `location.replace`, which I don't see any problem (it should works). Maybe you have browser settings that prevent script to open a new tab/window?

Comment: @elfan Sorry :/ Well no, because the browser blocks the "open" is a link that reviews a JSON array. How to bypass this restriction? Or there is another solution?

Comment: I found the solution myself: iframe not used (there Since a website if not distant USING AJAX) :)